# Trying to build a Blog with NextJS & MDX. However I keep coming across this error. Does anyone knows what this error means

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-error, mdxjs

[image: Error Message]
This is the error message that keeps on appearing when I click a link.
[image: Code Snippet]

Comment: Please use code snippets, do not use images for code.

Answer (score 1):

The Error come from a change in bundleMDX parameters in their last version.

The correct way of using it should be

```
   const source = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'posts', `${slug}.mdx`),
    'utf8'
  );

  const { code, frontmatter } = await bundleMDX({ source: source , ...});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you are trying to import a module on client-side but that module is for nodejs environment. you may try `mdx-bundler/client` as suggested here https://www.alaycock.co.uk/2021/03/mdx-bundler

The other way if moving all the parts to an api and call that api with one of these `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps` or inside of a `useEffect`

The link that I provided will solve your problems

Comment: From what OP posted, it looks like the error is happening on the server inside `getStaticProps`.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of SuperAmdine's answer, you can edit `getSourceOfFile` to be:

```
export const getSourceOfFile = (fileName) => {
  return fs.readFileSync(path.join(POSTS_PATH, fileName), 'utf8');
};
```

Notice the addition of `'utf8'`.

and then

```
const {code, frontmatter} = await bundleMDX( {
  source: source,
  cwd: POSTS_PATH,
});
```

(I'm following the same blog tutorial and this got it working for me)